# App service certificate is not being updated in KeyVault

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

We have an app *service certificate* which is set to renew automatically every year.

According to the overview and the timeline, a new certificate has already been created about a month ago.
However, when we try to export the certificate from KeyVault, the new version is not there. Only the old versions are listed.

We already tried to rekey the certificate, without any change.

What could be the cause of this?

**Update:**

After looking at https://resources.azure.com, I realized that the connection to KeyVault has broken down. No idea how to fix that...

```
      "properties": {
        "keyVaultId": "...",
        "keyVaultSecretName": "...",
        "provisioningState": "AzureServiceUnauthorizedToAccessKeyVault"
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that the access policies to the KeyVault got lost, probably during a subscription migration.

We fixed it like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
# Microsoft.CertificateRegistration
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName f3c21649-0979-4721-ac85-b0216b2cf413 -PermissionsToSecrets get,set,delete 
# Microsoft.Web
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

Credit to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-app-service-certificate-wildcard) for providing us with the correct service principal names.